# SQL Server : finding where the chain of hierarchy broke

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have more than 70k employee data in a table. It looks like this:

```
+----------------+----------------------+----------+
| EmployeeId     | name                 | ManagerID|
+----------------+----------------------+----------+
|              1 | Iron Man             | 2        |
|              2 | Batman               | 4        |
|              3 | Superman             | 2000     |
|              4 | Captain America      | 3        |    
+----------------+----------------------+----------+
```

Here, Superman has an invalid `ManagerID` because `ManagerID = 2000` doesn't exist in the `EmployeeID` column. In order to assign a new `ManagerID` for Superman, I need to find out at what level of hierarchy he is located. I know it should be some recursive query, but I am having much difficulty. Could anybody help? Thank you so much!

Comment: What would be the desired result of your query?   You don't have/generate a "Level of Hierarchy" column, so what value should be returned for Superman?

Comment: so Iron Man - Captain America - Superman, so Superman is at 3rd level of layer from the bottom until that chain is broken because Superman has invalid ManagerID. So I want something that returns 3 for Superman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you get started.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( EmployeeID INT, Name VARCHAR(200), ManagerID INT )
INSERT INTO Employees ( EmployeeID, Name, ManagerID ) VALUES ( 1, 'Iron Man', 2 ), ( 2, 'Batman', 4 ), ( 3, 'Superman', 2000 ), (4, 'Captain America', 3 )

WITH Relationships ( ManagerID, Name, EmployeeID ) AS
(
  SELECT
    ManagerID, Name, EmployeeID
  FROM
    Employees
  WHERE
    ManagerID IN ( SELECT EmployeeID FROM Employees )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Employees.ManagerID, Relationships.Name, Relationships.EmployeeID
  FROM
    Employees,
    relationships
  WHERE
    Employees.EmployeeID = Relationships.ManagerID
)
SELECT
  EmployeeID, Name, ManagerID
FROM
  Relationships
WHERE
  EmployeeID = 1 -- Iron Man
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 25000 )
```

Replace the "EmployeeID = 1" with whatever the Employee ID is that you want to target. The number of rows it returns is the level. You can probably add a ROW_NUM to the outermost query to get that value.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find out the broken records you can use *subquery* :

```
select * 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table where EmployeeId = t.ManagerID);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment! what is '1' in the subquery? (select 1 from table where..)